# php Sum values returned from a while loop inside a function

Tags: php, function, loops, while-loop, sum

I have written a function which returns a value from a while loop. I call this function 3 times and thus return 3 values. I want to sum these values. My function code is

```
<?php
function CalcTotal($Acc)
{   
    require('conn_bal.php');
    $query = "SELECT Dte, SUM(Cred), SUM(Deb) FROM tbl_account WHERE Acc='$Acc'"; 
    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$query)) {
        $TotBal = 0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            global $scred, $sdeb;
            $scred=$row['SUM(Cred)'];
            $sdeb=$row['SUM(Deb)'];
            $bal=$scred-$sdeb;
            global $TotBal;
            $TotBal = number_format($bal, 2);
            return $TotBal;
        }
    }  
}
?>
```

Which is called 3 different times i.e.

```
<?php
global $green;
$green = CalcTotal("Green");
echo $green;
echo "<br />";

global $blue;
$blue = CalcTotal("Blue");
echo $blue;
echo "<br />";

global $red;
$red = CalcTotal("Red");
echo $red;
echo "<br />";
?>
```

I then want to add these 3 returned values i.e.

```
<?php
global $Total;
$Total = $green + $blue + $red;
echo "Total: $Total";
?>
```

The correct values are being echoed but $Total = 3 The addition code is giving the count and is not summing the 3 returned variables.

I have tried all the permutations that I know and have researched this problem on the internet but to no avail.

If anyone has any ideas how I might achieve this I would be would be very grateful.

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you do `var_dump( $green );`?

Comment: I am pretty sure that `number_format(..)` will output a string, and I can imagine that php does not like adding strings and strings, or strings and floats together. Try `floatval( $green ) + floatval( $blue ) + floatval( $red )`.

Comment: Thank you for responding but I am afraid neither var_dump nor floatval work. floatval again gives the count of 3 and var_dump gives 0

Comment: What values are being echoed for green, red and blue?

Comment: `var_dump(..)` gives information about what a variable actually is. It will print it's type and a hopefully human-readable version of it's value. It can help in finding out what is in the variables when you try to add them to each other.

Comment: The echoed values are green = 1452.97, blue = 1344.48 and red = 1800.00

Comment: var_dump(..) gave the following information: string(8) "1,452.97" string(8) "1,344.48" string(8) "1,800.00" Total balances: 0